# Polymer binding - Why does linkPaths not work in this sample?

Tags: polymer

I have this sample:

```
Polymer({
        is: 'testElement',
        properties: {
            content: {
                type: Object,
                value: null
            },
            contentA: {
                type: Object,
                value: "testFoo"
            }
        },
        attached: function () {
            this.linkPaths("content", "contentA")
            this.set("contentA", "fooTest873");
            console.log(this.contentA);
            console.log(this.content);
        }
    });
```

I now try to get a functional binding between content and contentA, so that when contentA is updated content will be updated too.
Unfortunately this does not work in current Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure if this causes your problem, but you define both content and contentA as Objects, but then you use String values. Have you tried defining them as String or actually using Objects as values?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of linkPaths.
It currently only supports linking deep paths.

E.g. this.linkPaths("contentA.myProp", "contentB.myProp");

Also see this issue on github:
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2414